# Searching Dataframe for Specific Values to Be Stored

Tags: python, numpy, beautifulsoup

I'm new to programming and Python. I'm adopting code(https://github.com/rileypredum/East-Bay-Housing-Web-Scrape/blob/master/EB_Room_Prices.ipynb) to scrape Craiglist. My goal is to retrieve and store all the automotive posts in Chicago. I am able to store the Post Title, Post Time, Price, and Neighborhood. My next goal is to create a new column adding only the make of the vehicle, i.e. Toyota, Nissan, Honda, etc by searching the Post Title.  How do I do this?

I believe this would be where I would add logic here: In [13]" for a variable  "post_make" to search "post_title".

```
#build out the loop
from time import sleep
from random import randint
from warnings import warn
from time import time
from IPython.core.display import clear_output
import numpy as np

#find the total number of posts to find the limit of the pagination
results_num = html_soup.find('div', class_= 'search-legend')
results_total = int(results_num.find('span', class_='totalcount').text)

pages = np.arange(0, results_total, 120)

iterations = 0

post_timing = []
post_hoods = []
post_title_texts = []
post_links = []
post_prices = []

for page in pages:

    #get request
    response = get("https://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/eby/roo?" 
                   + "s=" 
                   + str(page) 
                   + "&hasPic=1"
                   + "&availabilityMode=0")

    sleep(randint(1,5))

    #throw warning for status codes that are not 200
    if response.status_code != 200:
        warn('Request: {}; Status code: {}'.format(requests, response.status_code))

    #define the html text
    page_html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    #define the posts
    posts = html_soup.find_all('li', class_= 'result-row')

    #extract data item-wise
    for post in posts:

        if post.find('span', class_ = 'result-hood') is not None:

            #posting date
            #grab the datetime element 0 for date and 1 for time
            post_datetime = post.find('time', class_= 'result-date')['datetime']
            post_timing.append(post_datetime)

            #neighborhoods
            post_hood = post.find('span', class_= 'result-hood').text
            post_hoods.append(post_hood)

            #title text
            post_title = post.find('a', class_='result-title hdrlnk')
            post_title_text = post_title.text
            post_title_texts.append(post_title_text)

            #post link
            post_link = post_title['href']
            post_links.append(post_link)

            post_price = post.a.text
            post_prices.append(post_price)


    iterations += 1
    print("Finished iteration: " + str(iterations))
```

Trying to figure out how to show the output.

Current output in excel is:
**posted, neighborhood, post title, url, price**

My goal is to add "post make" after the price.

I'm also looking for advice on how to show output from Jupyter notebooks here.

Comment: Hello, welcome the site. Could you please provide us with examples of inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: @N.Arunoprayoch added more detail. Thanks for the warm welcome.

Comment: your code will not run as is. You are missing the initial setting of html_soup for example.

Comment: there are no tags within the posts that specifically identify the make and model. The only part that indicates a make or model is the text/strings within the post title, url, or neighborhood (and even the neighborhood tag may not even include the neighborhood). So this will require additional work, such as NLP to try to pull out the make and model of the posted automobile.

Answer (score 0):

It's rather tricky to pull that out. I gave it a shot using another package Spacy to try to pull out the entities that are linked to organisations/car companies. It's not perfect, but it's a start:

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")



req_url = 'https://chicago.craigslist.org/search/cta'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Mobile Safari/537.36'}

payload = {
's': '0',
'query': 'automotive',
'sort': 'rel'}

response = requests.get(req_url, headers=headers, params=payload)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

total_posts = int(soup.find('span',{'class':'totalcount'}).text)
pages = list(range(0, total_posts, 120))






iterations = 0

post_timing = []
post_hoods = []
post_title_texts = []
post_links = []
post_prices = []
post_makes = []
post_models = []

for page in pages:
    payload = {
            's': page,
            'query': 'automotive',
            'sort': 'rel'}

    response = requests.get(req_url, headers=headers, params=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    posts = soup.find_all('li', class_= 'result-row')

    #extract data item-wise
    for post in posts:

        if post.find('span', class_ = 'result-hood') is not None:

            #posting date
            #grab the datetime element 0 for date and 1 for time
            post_datetime = post.find('time', class_= 'result-date')['datetime']
            post_timing.append(post_datetime)

            #neighborhoods
            post_hood = post.find('span', class_= 'result-hood').text
            post_hoods.append(post_hood)

            #title text
            post_title = post.find('a', class_='result-title hdrlnk')
            post_title_text = post_title.text
            post_title_texts.append(post_title_text)

            #post link
            post_link = post_title['href']
            post_links.append(post_link)

            post_price = post.a.text.strip()
            post_prices.append(post_price)

            try:
                # Used Spacy and Named Entity Recognition (NER) to pull out makes/models within the title text
                post_title_text = post_title_text.replace('*', ' ')
                post_title_text = [ each.strip() for each in post_title_text.split(' ') if each.strip() != '' ]

                post_title_text = ' '.join( post_title_text)

                doc = nlp(post_title_text)
                model = [ent.text for ent in doc.ents if ent.label_ == 'PRODUCT']

                make_model_list = [ent.text for ent in doc if ent.tag_ == 'NNP']

                doc = nlp(' '.join(make_model_list))
                make = [ent.text for ent in doc.ents if ent.label_ == 'ORG']

                post_make = make[0]
                post_makes.append(post_make)

                post_model = model[0]
                post_models.append(post_model)
            except:
                post_makes.append('')
                post_models.append('')





    iterations += 1
    print("Finished iteration: " + str(iterations))



data = list(zip(post_timing,post_hoods,post_title_texts,post_links,post_prices,post_makes,post_models))

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(post_timing,post_hoods,post_title_texts,post_links,post_prices,post_makes,post_models)),
                  columns = ['time','hood','title','link','price','make','model'])
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.head(20).to_string())
                time                                               hood                                              title                                               link   price                     make         model
0   2019-10-03 07:12             (TEXT 855-976-4304 FOR CUSTOM PAYMENT)  2015 Ford Focus SE Sedan 4D sedan Dk. Gray - F...  https://chicago.craigslist.org/chc/ctd/d/chica...  $11500            Ford Focus SE              
1   2019-10-03 06:03                  (EVERYBODY DRIVES IN SOUTH ELGIN)   $174/mo [][][] 2013 Hyundai Sonata BAD CREDIT OK  https://chicago.craigslist.org/nwc/ctd/d/south...    $174                             Sonata BAD
2   2019-10-03 00:04                  (EVERYBODY DRIVES IN SOUTH ELGIN)  $658/mo [][][] 2016 Jeep Grand Cherokee BAD CR...  https://chicago.craigslist.org/nwc/ctd/d/south...    $658                  Hyundai              
3   2019-10-02 21:04                  (EVERYBODY DRIVES IN SOUTH ELGIN)  $203/mo [][][] 2010 Chevrolet Traverse BAD CRE...  https://chicago.craigslist.org/nwc/ctd/d/south...    $203  Jeep Grand Cherokee BAD  Traverse BAD
4   2019-10-02 20:24                                           (DENVER)  2017 Jeep Cherokee Latitude 4x4 4dr SUV SKU:60...  https://chicago.craigslist.org/chc/ctd/d/denve...   $8995                               Cherokee
5   2019-10-02 20:03                              ( Buy Here Pay Here!)    Good Credit, Bad Credit, NO Credit = NO Problem  https://chicago.craigslist.org/nwc/ctd/d/chica...      $0                Chevrolet              
6   2019-10-02 20:03                              ( Buy Here Pay Here!)  Aceptamos Matricula!!! Te pagan en efectivo?? ...  https://chicago.craigslist.org/wcl/ctd/d/chica...      $0                     Jeep              
7   2019-10-02 20:02                              ( Buy Here Pay Here!)    Good Credit, Bad Credit, No Credit = No Problem  https://chicago.craigslist.org/chc/ctd/d/vista...      $0        Credit Bad Credit              
8   2019-10-02 20:00                              ( Buy Here Pay Here!)     Good Credit, Bad Credit, No Credit= No Problem  https://chicago.craigslist.org/sox/ctd/d/chica...      $0                                       
9   2019-10-02 19:15   (* CHRYSLER * TOWN AND COUNTRY * WWW.YOURCHOI...  2013*CHRYSLER*TOWN & COUNTRY*TOURING LEATHER K...  https://chicago.craigslist.org/nwc/ctd/d/2013c...   $9499                                       
10  2019-10-02 19:09         (*CADILLAC* *DTS* WWW.YOURCHOICEAUTOS.COM)  2008*CADILLAC*DTS*1OWNER LEATHER SUNROOF NAVI ...  https://chicago.craigslist.org/sox/ctd/d/2008c...   $5999        Credit Bad Credit              
11  2019-10-02 18:59   (WAUKEGANAUTOAUCTION.COM OPEN TO PUBLIC OVER ...  2001 *GMC**YUKON* XL DENALI AWD 6.0L V8 1OWNER...  https://chicago.craigslist.org/nch/ctd/d/2001-...   $1200                                       
12  2019-10-02 18:47    (*GMC *SAVANA *CARGO*  WWW.YOURCHOICEAUTOS.COM)  1999 *GMC *SAVANA *CARGO*G2500 SHELVES CABINET...  https://chicago.craigslist.org/sox/ctd/d/1999-...   $2999        Credit Bad Credit              
13  2019-10-02 18:04                              ( Buy Here Pay Here!)     GoodCredit, Bad Credit, No credit = No Problem  https://chicago.craigslist.org/nwc/ctd/d/chica...      $0                                       
14  2019-10-02 18:05                              ( Buy Here Pay Here!)                       Rebuild your credit today!!!  https://chicago.craigslist.org/sox/ctd/d/chica...      $0                 CHRYSLER              
15  2019-10-02 18:03                              ( Buy Here Pay Here!)  Rebuild your credit today!!! Repo? No Problem!...  https://chicago.craigslist.org/chc/ctd/d/vista...      $0                                       
16  2019-10-02 17:59           (* ACURA * TL * WWW.YOURCHOICEAUTOS.COM)  2006 *ACURA**TL* LEATHER SUNROOF CD KEYLES ALL...  https://chicago.craigslist.org/sox/ctd/d/2006-...   $4499                                       
17  2019-10-02 18:00                              ( Buy Here Pay Here!)  Buy Here Pay Here!!! We Make it Happen!! Bad C...  https://chicago.craigslist.org/wcl/ctd/d/chica...      $0                                       
18  2019-10-02 17:35                                          (ST JOHN)                                  2009 NISSAN VERSA  https://chicago.craigslist.org/nwi/ctd/d/saint...   $4995                                       
19  2019-10-02 17:33                                           (DENVER)  2013 Scion tC Base 2dr Coupe 6M SKU:065744 Sci...  https://chicago.craigslist.org/chc/ctd/d/denve...   $5995    GoodCredit Bad Credit
```